# How to compare hashes with bcrypt when the salt is different?

Tags: cryptography, bcrypt

There are different ways to perform a MAC, but without doubt the most used and efficient in many cases is HMAC, this serves to verify that the message has not been altered. A hash such as sha-256, sha-512 or bcrypt is regularly used.

That is my first doubt. bcrypt never generates the same hash, how do I see if the hash of the sender is equal to that of the receiver if they will never be the same (because they implement a SALT)?

Answer (score 2):

The sender needs to send the salt along with the hash so that the receiver uses the same salt when computing the bcrypt hash.

---

That said, bcrypt is designed to be a password hashing function, it's not meant to be used inside an HMAC. There is no need to use a salted hash with an HMAC, so I would suggest you use HMAC-SHA256.